# Poor results for TensorFlow Googlenet inception

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a version of Googlenet inception neural network however I am getting an accuracy of 10% with the [MNIST data set](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros). This is worrying because for simple neural networks I should get an accuracy of 97+% for this dataset. So I am confident that I have not implemented the inception neural network correctly. I have included my code below.

[image: The inception neural network that I am following]

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
import tensorflow as tf

x  = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None,784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.float32, shape = [None,10])

x_input = tf.reshape(x,[-1,28,28,1])


# 1x1 Convolution
W1x1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1,1,1]))
b1x1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
output1x1 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(x_input,W1x1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME'),b1x1)
output1x1 = tf.nn.relu(output1x1)


# 5x5 Convolution
W5x5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1,1,1]))
b5x5 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
output5x5 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(output1x1,W5x5, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME'),b5x5)
output5x5 = tf.nn.relu(output5x5)


# 3x3 Convolution
W3x3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1,1,1]))
b3x3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
output3x3 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(output1x1,W3x3, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME'),b3x3)
output3x3 = tf.nn.relu(output3x3)


# AveragePooling followed by 1x1 convolution
outputPool = tf.nn.avg_pool(output1x1, ksize = [1,2,2,1], strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = "SAME")
Wo1x1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,1,1,1]))
bo1x1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))
outputo1x1 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(outputPool,Wo1x1, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding = 'SAME'),bo1x1)
outputo1x1 = tf.nn.relu(outputo1x1)


# Concatonate the 4 convolution products
finalouput = tf.concat([output1x1, output5x5, output3x3, outputo1x1], 3)
finalouput = tf.reshape(finalouput, [-1, 7*7*64])

#Add a fully connected layer
W_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([7*7*64,1024]))
b_fc = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024]))  
output_fc = tf.add(tf.matmul(finalouput,W_fc), b_fc )
output_fc = tf.nn.relu(output_fc)
output_fc = tf.nn.dropout(output_fc, keep_prob = 0.85)

#Final layer
W_final = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024,10]))
b_final = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))
predictions = tf.add(tf.matmul(output_fc,W_final), b_final)


# Train the model
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = y_  ,logits = predictions))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(cost)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(20000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
        if i % 100 == 0:
            train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
            print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
        optimiser.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
    print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels,}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the weights initialization. The weights initialized using `tf.random_normal()` has a standard deviation of `1` which is high, reducing the number should fix the problem.

Change the weight initialization  to:

```
W** = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(..., stddev=0.01))
b** = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(..., stddev=0.001))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is very shadow. GoogLeNet has 22 layers.

I don't recommend implementing layers by yourself since it's error-prone. It's better to use tensorflow layer abstraction. You probably also want to look at or use existing implementation, for example, [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception).

Comment: But following the results from the algorithm in the picture, I should expect good results?

Comment: The picture you showed is only 1 layer. Depending on what you mean by good. You should be getting more than 10% with one layer. But if you want state of art results, which for mnist is more than 98%, you really need multiple layers.

Comment: Yeah for this particular data set, 10% is really bad even for one layer. But I can't identify what the issue is in my code

Comment: @James one layer should be enough to get results in the 90-100% range

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try concatenating it in a different order?